# Watching questions for answers

Tags: feature-request, questions

For questions I'd like to keep an eye on (e.g. to see if anyone else posts an answer) is there a way to maintain a list of such questions other than adding them as favourites or using the RSS feeds?

Comment: You can add them as bookmarks.

Comment: I thoroughly agree with this feature request. The only reason I have ever favourited questions is in the vague hope that some day they will be turned into a watch list, that would show up on a new tab on my responses page.

Comment: just came here looking for how to do this

Comment: please add this!!

Answer (score 14):

I second this very, very much. My favourites list is so full that it does not serve the purpose of *keeping track of questions* anymore. I'm sure everyone comes across questions every day where they'll think "I'd like to know the answer to that, too". You upvote it, favourite it, and forget it, until you clean up your favourite list a year later.

A notification feature informing about a question getting an accepted answer (or any other status change, like a bounty and maybe even a closing) would be very, very helpful indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you requesting for a feature that does the pretty much the exact same thing as two other features? What purpose would it serve other than replicating functionality found elsewhere?

Comment: To me, favouriting seems more like a long term thing e.g for questions you're going to refer back to regularly or for questions which have great discussion in the answers. I'm thinking more about a question I spot which hasn't been answered yet, and I don't know the answer myself, but I'd be interested in a notification when anyone else responds. I suppose I could add them as favourites and then remove them later.

Comment: That's why favorites can be added and removed.

Comment: @TheTXI, favorites are not the same as Watching, if i fav 30 items, there is  no proper way to know if there are new answers to them unless i save or remember the answer count on them, or to check with the last modified date of the question, this process relies on the user remembering info related to questions. Feeds are currently the only proper way to get this information, but adding of feeds every time is also cumbersome. I strongly think that a Watch feature is required and have been feeling the pain of not having that ever since SF and SU also launched.

Comment: There are two main reasons why Watching is different from Favoriting. The first is notification of changes, and the second is semantics. Maybe I want my favorites list to be what it says it is, not a huge mass of things I'm idly curious about.

This feature seems completely essential and I can't believe it doesn't exist.

Comment: I would expect a "watched" question to send me an email when there's an update. Maybe this simply means that starred questions should send such notifications, but I don't think it's the case right now, hence the feature.