# Display selected answers in a quicklist

Tags: feature-request, questions, user-interface

Speaking from my own experience, I find that my interest for questions is often quite temporary.

Sometimes this is because it a question I asked which I do not yet have an answer too, other times it can be a question that is still being discussed.

**Whatever the case may be, I find it very hard to actually get to the questions I am currently interested in *FAST*.**

Usually, I go to my profile page and either browse my own questions, or, if the question was asked by someone else and I participated, I look around in my recent activity or favorites.

In my opinion, there are **too many clicks involved** to get where you want. What I'd personally like to see is a function to mark a questions as "interesting". This mark is entirely personal and should not be shown to anyone else; interesting questions would then show up in a compact list on the top right of the website, just like the tags block, for example.

**Just to clarify: I believe the favorite mechanism works fine, but serves a totally different purpose, namely to store questions that interest me for the long term.**

I am looking for a way to easily stay up to date with questions that interest me *now*. My list of favorite questions is not private, is quite bulky and is hard to reach.

What are your views on this?

Answer (score 2):

I think we need a "watch list" for questions we'd like to see the answer on. I agree with you on the favorites - I use those more for long-term than short-term.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13066/watching-questions-for-answers-possible-feature-request

Answer (score 0):

We have the 'favorite' mechanism for that.

Click that star below the vote buttons on a question.  Then check out the favorites tab in your profile.

This is not private however.  You can see what other people have favorited.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The favorite mechanism does not suit this as these are often also long-term question (I actually never unfavorited a question). I am looking for a way to easily keep up to date with questions that interest me *now*

Comment: Unfavorite when you're done?

Comment: Well, why don't you just use favorites that way?  You can sort them by recent and see the most recently active ones.  Then un-favorite when activity dies down.

Comment: Even if I'd do that, I still think the interface is quite bulky and hard to reach. This is relevant information, which should be shown "dashboard-style": quick and simple, perhaps highlighting changed questions since last visit.

Comment: I guess I just disagree then.