# Feature Request: Feedback On Questions I've Answered

Tags: feature-request

I think this one might be fairly straight-forward.  The topic [Watching questions for answers (possible feature request)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13066/watching-questions-for-answers-possible-feature-request) touches on it, but doesn't completely describe what I am thinking of.

I think it would be helpful to get a notification if *anything* changes in a thread that I've provided an answer for.

This could include (but not be limited to nor all-inclusive):

- Another answer being accepted
- Another answer being added (may be TMI - perhaps something like an "answer counter" could be shown on the profile instead)
- The question being updated
- Comments on the question, or on other
  answers (although this point may
  result in TMI)

Perhaps this could be added to the user prefs, or perhaps this would muddy them too much.

Comments certainly welcome, and I will update with any clarifications as comments come in.

Comment: Favorite the question by clicking on the star icon under the voter.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/what-is-a-favorite-question-how-do-they-work. Updates are then on your `favorite` tab on the recent page (via the envelope).

Comment: @yhw42: this is also discussed in the link in the question.  However, it isn't really satisfactory - you would have to favorite every question you've ever answered, which is certainly not the intention of that feature.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to get notified if a question that I answer changes, even if I didn't star it as a favorite. Otherwise the only indication you receive is a rep leak, only to find out someone completely changed the question.

The rest of it seems like it would become annoying rather quickly, especially on questions that get lots of activity. The actual question changing is (for me) the only thing that might compel me to update my answer. I wouldn't change my answer if another was accepted, and I don't think I'd continuously update my answer to include things that other people wrote.

Still, I suppose it could be implemented in a way that you could check what notifications you'd like to receive.

Comment: the thinking was, in part, that I'd like to see if another answer was considered better than mine - I use SO as much as a learning tool as a teaching tool, sometimes at the same time.  I agree that some of the points would be overkill (unless configurable), especially on high-answer-traffic sites like Programmers.  Perhaps just an updated counter or something of the like.